# How to select the database dynamically

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

can I go like this

```
USE SELECT databasename from databasenametable
```

or something similar?

rather than do the select and then put the value in the use satement?  I tried brackets around the select and that didnt work.  the above didnt work either.  i wouldnt know what else to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, `USE` statement should get an explicit value for database name:

```
USE [databasename]
```

If you insist of doing this dynamically, you can use Dynamic Sql:

```
DECLARE @db AS NVARCHAR(258);
SET @db = QUOTENAME(N'Pubs'); -- put whatever you want here..
EXEC(N'USE ' + @db);
GO
```

Comment: so i cant do what im asking.  i got a bunch of db's and i know which one i want to use based on a query.  i want to put that query in my use statement, rather than give it an explicit value

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to execute one statement in another database, another alternative might be something like :

```
declare @sql nvarchar(500)
declare @yourDatabaseName nvarchar(50) = 'junk'
declare @yourQuery NVARCHAR(200) = 'select * from someTable'
set @sql = @yourDatabaseName + '..sp_executesql N''' + @yourQuery + ''''
EXEC (@sql)
```